# validate 2 arrays in a for

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to use 2 arrays to immediately use an if and validate which node it goes to, but only one node reads me, which is nod, can someone help me, regards!

```
function validatePagosNodes(nodes, nod) {
  let new_nodes = [];

  for (let node of nodes || nod) {
    monto += node.getAttribute("Monto");
    for (let child of node.children) {
      if (child.length > 0) {
        if (child.nodeName == "pago20:DoctoRelacionado") new_nodes.push(child);
      } else {
        if (child.nodeName == "Pago20:DoctoRelacionado") new_nodes.push(child);
      }
    }
  }
}
return new_nodes;
}
```

Comment: What ids `monto`? Why does your inner `if` have identical code for both branches? Why does this take two arguments and then default one to the other? Why not take one and let the caller deal with that?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If `nodes` is never read, then I would add the line `console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes));` inside your function to see what it is if you're expecting it to be an array.

Comment: The value of `nodes || nod` is `nodes` if it's a truthy value, otherwise it's `nod`.

Comment: You have too many `}` characters in the function, so `return new_nodes;` is not inside the function.

Comment: @phatfingers That's what I said (after my edit). I initially assumed `nodes` would always be an array, and all arrays are truthy, even if they're empty.

Comment: @Barmar Yup.  So, if he's only seeing `nod`, then nodes could be something unexpected, like null.

Comment: The point is that it won't use both values. It will either use `nodes` or `nod`, whichever is set, but not both.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contributions, I give you a little more context, what this function does is read a part of an xml document, in this document there are headers called: 'Pago20:Pagos' (it is assigned as nodes)
'pago20:Pagos' (it is assigned as nod)

Comment: So when this xml is read and it reaches the ValidatePagosNodes function, what is done is to see if node is nodes or nod, to immediately join it with the amount attribute (which is a number), then that node passes to child and this is when I ask if child > 0 and if child has as nodeName 'pago20:DoctoRelacionado'
if it does not go to 'Payment20:DoctoRelacionado'
and returns new_nodes

what happens with me is that it only reads a value in this case the first one that is nodes and || nod does not respect it and does not pass as node this is my big unknown

Comment: I hope I have explained in a good way I send you an affectionate greeting